# Get best match for a join in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to get results from Ms SQL query, sorted by best match. This means that I have two tables like this

```
CREATE TABLE #Leads(
    Id          INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    LeadId      INT,
    PlanId      INT,
    RegionCode  VARCHAR(20),
    FuelType    VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE #Discounts(
    Id              INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    PlanId          INT,
    RegionCode      VARCHAR(20),
    FuelType        VARCHAR(20),
    DiscountPercent DECIMAL(6,3)
)
```

And these tables have following values like below

```
INSERT INTO #Leads([LeadId], [PlanId], [RegionCode], [FuelType])
    VALUES (1,1,'HR26', 'Petrol'),  
           (2,2,'HR30', 'Diesel')

INSERT INTO #Discounts ([PlanId], [RegionCode], [FuelType], [DiscountPercent])
                VALUES (1, null, null, 20),
                       (2, null, null, 10),
                       (2, 'HR30', null, 15),
                       (2, null, 'Diesel', 20),
                       (2, 'HR30', 'Diesel', 25)
```

So If we join `#leads` tables with `#discounts` table by `PlanId` then -

for `Plan 1` we don't have multiple discount entries so we will pick first one it will be `20%`

but for Plan 2 we get data as :-

**Case 1:** We have multiple discount entries for Plan 2 now with current case it should pick 25% because `RegionCode` and `FuelType` both matched with lead.

**Case 2:** If I update `Plan 2` lead and change `RegionCode to NULL`( or any value that don't matches in discount table for `Plan 2`) then it should pick `20%.`

**Case 3:** If I update `Plan 2` lead and change `FuelType to NULL`(or any value that don't matches in discount table for `Plan 2`) and RegionCode back to `HR30` then it should pick `15%`

**Case 4:** If I change both of them to `NULL` (or any value that don't matches in discount table for `Plan 2`) then it should pick `10%.`

I want the best possible match for `Plan2`

I have no idea how to write a query for this please help - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question, here is one way to do it:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT  LeadID, 
        (
        CASE WHEN l.RegionCode = d.RegionCode THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN l.FuelType = d.FuelType THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        -- + more of the same here
        ) As Match,    
        d.DiscountPercent
FROM #Leads As l
JOIN #Discounts As d
    ON l.PlanId = d.PlanId
)

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES LeadID, DiscountPercent
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LeadID ORDER BY Match DESC)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, the solution which you suggested works for 2 columns  but In my case I  forgot to mention I have 20 columns in my tables for matching like
- RegionCode
- FuelType
- Column 3
- Column 4

Comment: So it would be difficult to add a match condition for all columns in CTE

Comment: does a match on `RegionCode` caries more weight than a match on `FuelType` (like in my query), or all matches weigh the same? If the last, what do you do when you have two records matching on the same number of columns, but on different columns?

Comment: All matches weigh same there is no such  weightage. Also FuelType of #Leads is to be matched with FuelType of #Discounts table, same applies for all column.

Comment: I've edited my answer so that all matches weigh the same. I'm not sure if there's an easier way to do it. Perhaps some other answer will show an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can help from my experience. But I can only help query per cases.

Case 1 :

```
SELECT * FROM #Leads l INNER JOIN #Discounts d ON l.PlanId = d.PlanId AND l.RegionCode = d.RegionCode and l.FueLType = d.FuelType
```

Case 2 :

```
SELECT * FROM #Leads l INNER JOIN #Discounts d ON l.PlanId = d.PlanId AND l.FuelType = d.FuelType
```

Case 3 :

```
SELECT * FROM #Leads l INNER JOIN #Discounts d ON l.PlanId = d.PlanId AND l.RegionCode= d.RegionCode
```

Case 4 :

```
SELECT * FROM #Leads l INNER JOIN #Discounts d ON l.PlanId = d.PlanId
```

This is all I can help. Maybe it can gives you some idea or something. And maybe someone more experienced can help. Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to be in a single query :)

Comment: Whoops, then I hope someone can help :) But I hope my query can give you some thoughts. GL !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from #Leads l  
join #Discounts d  
   on d.PlanId=l.PlanId  
   and d.[DiscountPercent]=(select max([DiscountPercent]) from #Discounts 
                          where PlanId=l.PlanId 
                          and ((FuelType=l.FuelType and RegionCode=l.RegionCode)
                            or (FuelType=l.FuelType and RegionCode is null)
                            or (FuelType is null and RegionCode=l.RegionCode)
                            or (FuelType is null and RegionCode is null)))
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for you reply, but it will not work as I don't have fixed number of columns :)